# twitter-bootstrap typeahead RTL - wrong position

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm using twitter-bootstrap typeahead to fetch data from the server and to display it as user types.

the problem is that my site is RTL which makes the results box to be unaligned.

On chrome the results box is aligned to the most right and on FF it shows on the left side of the input.

i was trying to search for it and no solution seemed to work.

This is the hardcoded style twitter-bootstrap applies:

```
<ul class="typeahead dropdown-menu dropdown-fixed" style="top: 191px; left: 849px; display: none;">
```

any ideas how to align it properly?
10x

Answer (score 0):

i got it working by removing the left attribute of:

```
this.$menu.insertAfter(this.$element).css({top:b.top+b.height,left:b.left}).show(),this.shown=!0,this}
```

and used a fixed right position for the dropdown.